# update input number while typing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to do an input html using angular 2+ that contains number and have a min and max.
I want that if user type a number smaller than minimum input will be updated with min and get this message : the autorized minimum number is 2.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for ?

If yes, you could easily improve it using Validators.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  min = 5;
  max = 15;
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      num: new FormControl('')
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form.get('num').valueChanges
    .pipe(debounceTime(500))
    .subscribe(value => {
      if (!value) {
        return;
      }

      if (value < this.min) {
        this.form.setValue({
          num: this.min
        }, {
          emitEvent: false
        });
      } else if (value > this.max) {
        this.form.setValue({
          num: this.max
        }, {
          emitEvent: false
        })
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="number" formControlName="num" placeholder="Type a number"/>
</form>
```